# single-row sub query return more than one row in procedure

Tags: oracle10g

procedure below throws exception

single-row sub query return more than one row

while executing query on sql> query execute fine and shows result
as expected

```
create or replace procedure discount_purchase(cust_name customer1.cust_name%type)
as
    amt int;
    discount int;
begin
    select sum(purch_amt) into amt
    from orders
    where customer_id=(select customer_id from customer1 where cust_name=cust_name);
    dbms_output.put_line('Total amount is='||amt);

    if(amt>=500) then
        discount:=amt-(0.25*amt);
        dbms_output.put_line('Discount amount is='||discount);
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('NO Discount on='||amt||'Discount only above 500');
    end if;
end;
/
```

­
    SQL> exec discount_purchase('Nick Rimando');

```
BEGIN discount_purchase('Nick Rimando'); END;
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
ORA-06512: at "ARPAN.DISCOUNT_PURCHASE", line 6
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Comment: use alias name and get first row of subquery

Comment: sub query return single value 3002 as customer_id

Comment: Try to add and rownum=1 to your subquery conditions if you DO NOT care about the value from the list or DO sure that they are the same.

Comment: see https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01427.php

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have multiple customers in the `customer1` table with the `cust_name` of `'Nick Rimando'`. Have a look at

```
select count(1)
from customer1
where cust_name = 'Nick Rimando';
```

I bet it will result in a number higher than 1.

**The fix(es)**

The fix depends on what you actually need. And you actually did not write what you need. So, a few cases come to my mind...

**Case 1 - Sum of purchases of all customers with that name**

```
create or replace procedure discount_purchase(cust_name customer1.cust_name%type)
as
    amt int;
    discount int;
begin
    select sum(purch_amt) into amt
    from orders
    where customer_id in (select customer_id from customer1 where cust_name=cust_name);
    dbms_output.put_line('Total amount is='||amt);

    if(amt>=500) then
        discount:=amt-(0.25*amt);
        dbms_output.put_line('Discount amount is='||discount);
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('NO Discount on='||amt||'Discount only above 500');
    end if;
end;
/
```

**Case 2 - Sum of purchases of arbitrary single customer with that name**

```
create or replace procedure discount_purchase(cust_name customer1.cust_name%type)
as
    amt int;
    discount int;
begin
    select sum(purch_amt) into amt
    from orders
    where customer_id = (select customer_id from customer1 where cust_name=cust_name and rownum <= 1);
    dbms_output.put_line('Total amount is='||amt);

    if(amt>=500) then
        discount:=amt-(0.25*amt);
        dbms_output.put_line('Discount amount is='||discount);
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('NO Discount on='||amt||'Discount only above 500');
    end if;
end;
/
```

**Case 3 - Sum of purchases of "the first" customer with that name**

```
create or replace procedure discount_purchase(cust_name customer1.cust_name%type)
as
    amt int;
    discount int;
begin
    select sum(purch_amt) into amt
    from orders
    where customer_id = (select min(customer_id) from customer1 where cust_name=cust_name);
    dbms_output.put_line('Total amount is='||amt);

    if(amt>=500) then
        discount:=amt-(0.25*amt);
        dbms_output.put_line('Discount amount is='||discount);
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('NO Discount on='||amt||'Discount only above 500');
    end if;
end;
/
```

**Case 4 - you choose, you implement**

I can't tell you how, that is solely up to you and your design considerations.

**Case 5 - Fix your data model**

Again, I can't tell you how, that is solely up to you and your design considerations.